# Orthogonal basis functions in `mgcv`

Tags: r, spatial, mgcv

I have a spatial dataset that I'm modeling using penalized splines from `mgcv`. Here's a simplified example of what it looks like:

[image]

For simplicity, I'm modelling some response value `y` as a smoothed function of `distance` to the boundary area. I also have a spatial smoother to account for spatial variation that isn't related to distance:

```
m1 <- gam(y ~ s(distance) + s(E,N), data = ...)
```

Is there a way to restrict the `s(E,N)` basis functions to be orthogonal to the `s(distance)` basis functions, so that any distance-based variation gets modelled by the *distance* smoother rather than the *spatial* smoother?